# HTML - mailto does not work

Tags: html

I wrote an email link on a webpage. It works fine for me, but my customers are telling me, that outlook/thunderbird does not open for them. I assume they are using a mac'/safari. Any ideas, why it does not work for them?

HTML

```
<a  href="mailto:my.addy@gmail.com" target="_top">my.addy@gmail.com</a>
```

Comment: Probably they don't have any program configured to handle mailto URI scheme.

Comment: They told it is working for them with other websites, maybe I should ask them which ones

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is fine.  Your customers' computers are not configured correctly and there is nothing you can do about that.  Many folks don't have a `mailto:` handler set up, especially these days where so many people use web-based e-mail.

Also note that `target="_top"` has no effect here.